# Queue up javascript code in a single process

Tags: node.js, cron, queue, task, setinterval

Lets say I have a bunch of tasks in an object, each with a date object. I was wondering if it's even possible to have tasks within the object be run within a single process and trigger when the date is called.

Here's an example:

```
var tasks = [
  "when": "1501121620",
  "what": function(){
    console.log("hello world");
  },
  "when": "1501121625",
  "what": function(){
    console.log("hello world x2");
  },
]
```

I'm fine with having these stored within a database and the `what` script being `eval`ed from a string. I need a point in the right direction. I've never seen anything like this in the node world.

I'm thinking about using [`hotload`](https://github.com/jan-swiecki/node-hotload) and using the file system so I don't need to deal with databases.

Should I just look into `setInterval` or is there something out there that is more sophisticated? I know things like `cron` exist, the thing is I need all of these tasks to occur within an already existing running process. I need to be able to add a new task to the queue without ending the process.

To add a little context I need some way of queuing up socket.io `.emit()` functions.

Comment: Does your queue must be persistent? Does it have to scale across more than one instance? Do your tasks must be triggered with millisecond accuracy?

Comment: I need the tasks to exist in the queue until fulfilled, a record of past queues is also required. Once instance. Not necessary to be triggered within millisecond.

Comment: You need a background worker. Some googling gave me this: https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue

Comment: If you would consider using Redis a database, then kue module can be what you are searching for, especially with its [delayed jobs feature](https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue/#delayed-jobs) which uses Redis PUB/SUB system. You can create and consume jobs in the same script = single process. It's a very powerful and elastic solution, but may be to big for you.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin it doesn't look like kue has the ability to set a task to a specific future time and have it run. which https://github.com/mattpat/node-schedule and https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) package from npm. He is written pure on js (using second variant from bellow). So all of these tasks will occur within an already existing running process. For example your can create `CronJob` like this:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob(1421110908157);
job.addCallback(function() { /* some stuff to do */ });
```

In pure javascript you can do it only through `setTimeout` and `setInterval` methods. There are two variants:

1) Set interval callback, which will check your task queue and execute callbacks in appropriate time:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; ii = tasks.length; ++i) {
        var task = tasks[i];

        if (task.when*1000 < Date.now()) {
            task.what();
            tasks.splice(i,1);
            --i;
        }
    };
}, 1000);

As you see accuracy of callback calling time will be dependent on interval time. Less interval time => more accuracy, but also more CPU usage.
```

2) Create wrapper around your tasks. So when you want to add new task you're calling some method `addTask`, that will be calling `setTimeout` with your task callback. Beware that maximum time for `setTimeout` is 2147483647ms (around 25 days). So if your time exceeds max time, you must set timeout on the maximum time with callback which will be set new timeout with remaining time. For example:

```js
var MAX_TIME = 2147483647;
function addTask(task) {
   if (task.when*1000 < MAX_TIME) {
       setTimeout(task.what, task.when);
   }
   else {
       task.when -= MAX_TIME/1000;
       setTimeout(addTask.bind(null, task), MAX_TIME);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is really great! I think the trickier issue, which may be out-of-scope for this question, is the ability to add items to a queue with the process still running. Even if I had some way to get them all in a database I need some way of for the process to get them into the queue.

Comment: I'm not sure if it uses native cron which wouldn't work for me because I wanna use it on heroku. I asked https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron/issues/134

Comment: @ThomasReggi It does not use any libraries. As I wrote to you, it uses second variant from my answer. Look [here](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron/blob/master/lib/cron.js#L427).

Comment: @ThomasReggi As you see: `start()` method sets timeout with `callbackWrapper`, which in turn whether are calling callbacks for that cron job or sets timeout again with itself as callback.